# How to access nested inner key-values directly in YAML unmarshall

Tags: go, yaml

My configs contain multiple structured configs of an inner struct, in this case- a company.

At the top-level, I want access directly to a particular attribute in a company I know exists in my config.yaml.

Is it possible to have this unmarshalling using just struct tags?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

type Org struct {
    Ceo string `yaml:"ceo"`
}

type Config struct {
    Companies map[string]Org `yaml:"companies"`
    GoogleCEO string         `yaml:"companies.google.ceo"`
}

func main() {
    var config Config

    yamlFile := []byte(`companies:
  google:
    ceo: "Sundar Pichai"
  amazon:
    ceo: "Jeff Bezos"`)
    err := yaml.Unmarshal(yamlFile, &config)
    check(err)

    fmt.Printf("config:\n%#v", config)
}

func check(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/G_1NV46yWrv

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot do it with tags.

Closest option is nested structs:

```golang
type Config struct {
    Companies struct {
        Google struct {
            CEO string `yaml:"ceo"`
        } `yaml:"google"`
    } `yaml:"companies"`
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/28pcPUiZvO-